# Using Array Formula with Median and IF

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, median

I'm trying to find the median of a column based on two conditions. I thought using an ArrayFormula is best since there is no "medianifs"...I'm getting a result in my first cell but when I try to change the criteria in the cell beneath, you'll see I'm getting the exact same result, so I know something is wrong. Maybe the formula in the first cell isn't even the correct answer?

[Here's my sheet.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Nnxma9UdX_zVHkIOC_F4fwwylkzvf7gB_nmdZDR4Bq0/edit#gid=2041786543)
I'm down in P94 and P95 trying to get the median values, you'll see the formulas that I've tried thus far.

Comment: your sheet shows "access denied"

Comment: without a shared sample permanently shared here, I'm afraid this question and subsequent answer will not be useful to anyone in the future.  Could you please leave up a sample or elaborate on the data layout a bit more in the question so that the answer can be a good resource to others in the future?

Comment: Yep it's fixed now @MattKing, I had discovered there was sensitive information in the sheet by mistake and dropped access while I removed it, which took a litle bit of time because there were formulas dependent on the sensitive info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what you are attempting, I would use a filter to narrow down the criteria.

```
=MEDIAN(FILTER(N:N,F:F=O1,I:I=P1))
```

That way the data you are taking the median of is always the exact dataset needed.